# Webservice Do Something when a file is uploaded to server

Tags: node.js

I'm setting up a new server, and want to set a middleware to listen when a file is uploaded to server.
Example: someone enter in WinSCP and upload a file to my server, so this middleware will get the informations about this file, like date modify and name.

Need something linke express.upload('', function(req,res,next){})

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: That's my problem, i can't find any example or help :'( . I know how to do when a file is uploaded using node.js, but i need when a file come to server from any way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using chokidar.

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('file, dir, or glob', {
  ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true
});

var log = console.log.bind(console);

watcher
  .on('add', function(path) { log('File', path, 'has been added'); })
  .on('addDir', function(path) { log('Directory', path, 'has been added'); })
  .on('change', function(path) { log('File', path, 'has been changed'); })
  .on('unlink', function(path) { log('File', path, 'has been removed'); })
  .on('unlinkDir', function(path) { log('Directory', path, 'has been removed'); })
  .on('error', function(error) { log('Error happened', error); })
  .on('ready', function() { log('Initial scan complete. Ready for changes.'); })
  .on('raw', function(event, path, details) { log('Raw event info:', event, path, details); })
```

Doing that my webservice will watch this folder and all subdirectory.